# Prove if a property of a Turing Machine is decidable or not, how can I do it?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, halting-problem

I cannot understand how to prove if a certain property of a Turing Machine M is decidable or not.

For example, if a have this:

(1.1) "M always halts within 100 steps"

or this

(1.2) "M recognizes all words with an ‘a’ in them"

what do I do to prove if it's decidable or not? I know I should use reduction or diagonalization, halting problem and so on, but I don't know how to apply them.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can also use [Rice’s theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)

Comment: Yes but how? That's the problem

Comment: It is not a formal notion when you talk about the property of a machine. Rice theorem only states that the set of TM representations which languages satisfy a non-trivial property is undecidable.

Comment: One of your examples is actually decidable. To show that, give an algorithm deciding it.

Answer (score 2):

To show that a language is decidable, you need to provide a description of a **total** Turing machine, i.e, on all input, the Turing machine should **halt** and accept or **halt** and reject. 
Take the example of the first problem, we can build a total Turing machine, that on input $M$(where $M$ is a Turing machine) runs it all inputs of length at most 100. Note that if $M$ halts on all inputs within 100 steps, then it must halt on all inputs of length at most 100 within those many number of steps. If $M$ does so, our constructed Turing machine halts and accepts, else halts and rejects. Since  we have to check only on a *finite* number of input strings, the constructed machine always halts and hence is *total*. 
As for the second problem, the property of accepting all strings with an 'a' in them is a non-trivial one for recursively enumerable sets($L(M)$ or the language recognized by a Turing machine $M$ is an R.E set) and hence from Rice's theorem, the language of deciding recursively enumerable sets with this very property is undecidable.